# Get all the Up ip in the local network -java

Tags: java, networking, ip, subnet

For the Java project i need to scan the list of ip connected to the same local network via wlan or eth0 or anything. I need to get the **list of ip address that are up in the local network**.

I tried

```
InetAddress localHost = Inet4Address.getLocalHost();
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localHost);

for (InterfaceAddress address : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) 
{
        System.out.println(address.getNetworkPrefixLength());
}
```

But it gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.Server.Subnet.main(Subnet.java:17)
```

I think i need to follow these steps.

1. Get the subnet address of the network that i connected
2. Scan all the ip address in the subnet mask
3. List the ip address that are up

Can you give me the right implementation way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this program to find all the up ip in the subnet of the system connected.

```
package com.Server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InterfaceAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Subnet
{
    public void Subnet() throws UnknownHostException, SocketException
    {
        Enumeration e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
            Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
            while (ee.hasMoreElements())
            {
                InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
                String ip = i.getHostAddress();

                String sip = ip.substring(0, ip.indexOf('.',ip.indexOf('.',ip.indexOf('.')+1) + 1) + 1);
                try {
                    for(int it=1;it<=255;it++)
                    {
                        String ipToTest = sip+it;
                        boolean online = InetAddress.getByName(itToTest).isReachable(100);
                        if (online) {
                            System.out.println(ipToTest+" is online");
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println(sip);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your modem is not masking others IP.

Comment: Package `com.Client` is not found ! ,did you post a complete code ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these directions
  -- get your system IP
  -- get your subnet mask.
  -- As per your subnet mask, get the list of possible IP addresses in your subnet.&
  -- Now, one by one ping them. (you can use system ping command with java)
  -- check ping response, then you can decide whether the host is up or not.